# Selenium IDE: Test works with firefox webdriver but not with htmlunitdriver

Tags: selenium

Disclaimer: I've never used any test tools before, as I'm in the developer team, not the QA team.

Our team is tasked with the ultimate goal of writing an automated load test script, which will be hitting on our JS-based web application. We will most likely be using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

As we're taking it one step at a time, we started with writing test scripts using [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) with Firefox driver, then migrate to [HtmlUnitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) as we want to eventually run multiple instance of the tests at the same time. We are running selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar in the background. The Selenium IDE has WebDriver playback enabled, and is using "selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar", "htmlunit-2.13.jar", and "htmlunit-core-js-2.13.jar" as the IDE extensions.

The test will load our login page (which, unfortunately, contains `<iframe>`), login to our dashboard page, check for existing text, and logout from that page.

Here is a simplified portion of the login page:

```
<html>
<head><title>footest</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="container" align="center">
        <div id="login">
            <div id="login-panel">

                <iframe src="http://localhost/auth/form">

                    <div id='login-form'>

                        <form action="http://localhost/auth/form" method="post">
                        <div class='row'>
                            <label for='username' class='vertical'>Username</label>
                            <input class="text" id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
                        </div>

                        <div class='row'>
                            <label for='password' class='vertical'>Password</label>
                            <input class="text" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" />
                        </div>

                        <div class='row'>
                            <input class="float-right" id="login" name="login" type="submit" value="Log In" />
                        </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                </iframe>

            </div><!-- login-panel -->
        </div><!-- login -->  
    </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the steps we recorded with Selenium IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://localhost/dashboards/" />
<title>footest</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">footest</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://localhost/dashboards?back=http%3A//localhost/dashboards/main.html</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>index=0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForText</td>
    <td>//label</td>
    <td>Username</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>//input[@id='username']</td>
    <td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typeAndWait</td>
    <td>//input[@id='password']</td>
    <td>bar1234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//input[@id='login']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>20000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForText</td>
    <td>id=graph-table</td>
    <td>No records found</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//a[@id='logout']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

When we run the tests with WebDriver playback + firefox browser, we are able to run the test successfully. However, when we switch to using htmlunit, we were not able to run it. The error is as follows:

```
17:28:25.432 INFO - Command request: getText[//label, ] on session 87338f89-7d2f-4387-b85e-3685a1a8a2ac
17:28:27.135 INFO - Got result: ERROR,Element //label not found on session 87338f89-7d2f-4387-b85e-3685a1a8a2ac
```

Similar error occured on selecting the input field with id='username', or clicking on the logout button at the end.

The questions are:

1. How can we reliably run the scripts without spawning a browser?
2. Are we going in the right direction with using HtmlUnit?
3. Any other tools / hints / etc. we should consider to test this without browser?

Comment: Why are you going this route if you want to do load testing? Why not dive straight into JMeter? Selenium is great for functional tests but not the tool of choice for performance

Comment: We had functional test scripts written in Selenium (by the QA team), which we thought might be able to integrate to load test. Also, when we looked at JMeter initially, we got the impression that it does not fully support testing ajax-based / scripted websites. That's why we thought of creating scripts in Selenium and then convert it to be executed by JMeter.

Comment: Maybe try reading this - http://theworkaholic.blogspot.com/2010/11/jmeter-and-ajax-part-i.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Selenium tests are always run against a browser. HTMLUnit mimics a browser in a headless form.
2. Running tests against a headless browser is great for faster feedback during development, but in the long run you will want to run your tests against real browsers to find browser compatibility issues.
3. Did you try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), its a headless webkit browser. I know of teams that run the tests vs PhantomJS first locally, before they fire it up against a grid like [Saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/) to test all different browsers. If you Google on PhantomJS and Webdriver you will find a lot of people playing with it, like this blog post: http://itkosmopolit.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/quick-start-of-running-selenium-webdriver-against-phantomjs-in-java-on-windows/. As it is a "real" browser you can also take screenshots in a headless mode. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on PhantomJS. It looks promising. We'll check it out and hopefully can get something out of it.

Comment: We checked out the example from IT-Kosmopolit and were able to run some basic test scripts. However now we are confused: Should we write scripts in JS per the example in the site, as well as [these (1)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/yPdrsS3KOJ4) [people (2)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/YIBorm32dnM/-hIp0t0M4BYJ), or do we keep writing it in Java and just use PhantomJS as the driver?

Comment: I would stick with what you know, keep using Java and PhantomJS as a browser which supports webdriver. Found another post about using Java and PhantomJS http://www.appneta.com/blog/automated-testing-java/

Comment: We continued to use Java, which is like what you suggested. We still couldn't figure out how to select certain elements such as `<iframe>`, and are looking into how to take screenshots of steps in our tests to see whether we are doing things correctly. Now what we need is to brush up our Java and webdriver skills.

Comment: Bit of topic, but Selenium handles iFrames as an window which you have to switchTo(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/handling-iframe-in-webdriver . Goodluck with learning! :)

Comment: We tried using `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` since our iframe has no `id`. But we couldn't get the element inside the iframe for some reason. We probably got it wrong since most examples point to similar command. But we'll put that aside and use other workarounds for now, as we're kind of rushed on this. :(

Comment: Wonder why no upvotes (yet) for this excellent answer. Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE is not a reliable way to create tests. It would be a maintenance nightmare. You might be better of using the webdriver package as such. It supports multiple programming languages. If you know Java, Python or C#, you should be able to pick it up in a day. Most QA teams forget that test automation is software development after all.
Let me know if you do face any specific issues.

Comment: We sort of noticed that, too. However, since we have limited Java knowledge and there are not too many examples using Python, we thought of using Selenium IDE as a base and expand from there. Most examples we saw show us how to perform search with Google. There's not many on selecting iFrame and JS-generated texts. But thanks for the input. We'll try to look into it.